# Data saved as null when using RadioButtonList or dropDownList

Tags: yii

I'm new to yii. I have this problem where my data stored in radiobuttonlist or dropDownList is not saved in the database. It always shows as null. here's my code

**View:**

```
<?php
 $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); 
 echo $form->label($model,'gender');
 echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'gender',array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female'));
echo $form->label($model,'cat');
 echo $form->dropDownList($model,'cat',$category);
 echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
 $this->endWidget();
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Test;
        if(isset($_POST['Test']))
        {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['Test'];
                        if($model->save()){
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
                        }
                        else
                            var_dump($model->errors);
        }
                $cat = array('st'=>'STAFF','ot'=>'OTHERS');
                $model->gender='M';
        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,'category'=>$cat
        ));
    }
```

Kindly help... Thanks in advance

**EDIT: After adding the *required* in the rule section it works like a charm**

Well here's the modified Test model

```
public function rules()
    {

        return array(
            array('gender,cat', 'required'),
            array('name', 'length', 'max'=>45),

        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your model here.I think your problem is in Test model.

Comment: Yes you were right. I forgot to add the required rules for gender and cat columns. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved it using `'required'`, but if there are some fields that are not mandatory, you can just use the `'safe'` rule. The point is that every attribute of your form has to be on the rules of your model.

Have a look to [Understanding "Safe" Validation Rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/).